# Values from object like keys in dictionary doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have created object in javascript like

```
function MetaEntity(){
this.energy = "energy";
this.name = "name";
}

var meta = new MetaEntity();
```

when I try to use values from meta like keys in dictionary it doesn't work.

```
var c = {meta.energy: 100,
         meta.name : "tekton"}
```

Can tell me what is a problem?

Comment: You need to be much more specific than "it doesn't work." Is there an error? What do you expect to see? What do you actually see?

Comment: @JacobKrall page throws error with content empty {}, I have tried in command line (node.js) but it cannot create c dictionary and stays ... and no return to prompt to continue to enter new commands

Comment: @PaolaJ you have the python programmer syndrome - same like me xDDD. ran into this error many times. see any answer, they're all right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function MetaEntity(){
    this.energy = "energy";
    this.name = "name";
}

var meta = new MetaEntity();

var c = {meta.energy: 100,
         meta.name : "tekton"}
```

will not work as you expect. will not try to produce {"energy": 100, "name": "tekton"} but {"meta.energy": 100, "meta.name": "tekton"}, which is not allowed in literal objects or will not produce the effect you want.

assign field by field: c = {}; c[meta.energy] = 100; c[meta.name] = "tekton";

Answer (score 1):

```
var c = {}
c[meta.energy] = 100;
c[meta.name] = "tekton";
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use this syntax:

```
var c = {};
c[meta["energy"]]= 100;
c[meta["name"]]= "tekton";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use variables when you are defining an object that way.

```
var c = {meta.energy: 100,
     meta.name : "tekton"
};
```

would need to be

```
var c = {};
c[meta.energy] = 100;
c[meta.name] = "tekton";
```

Other options is to extend the object.